# import csv file into datagridview with specific column and row in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview, import, showdialog

Please help me guys, its my first time to try importing excel file to datagridview in vb.net. The scenario is that my excel file have so many data and i only need to import the value  starting in column B to column I, and start rows must be in column B with the word  "START" and ends in the row with the word "END". So far this was my code:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv"

    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog(Me) = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

        Try
            Dim fi As New FileInfo(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
            Dim sConnectionStringz As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties=Text;Data Source=" & fi.DirectoryName
            Dim objConn As New OleDbConnection(sConnectionStringz)
            objConn.Open()
            'DataGridView1.TabIndex = 1
            Dim objCmdSelect As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM " & fi.Name, objConn)
            Dim objAdapter1 As New OleDbDataAdapter
            objAdapter1.SelectCommand = objCmdSelect
            Dim objDataset1 As New DataSet
            objAdapter1.Fill(objDataset1)
            '--objAdapter1.Update(objDataset1) '--updating
            DataGridView1.DataSource = objDataset1.Tables(0).DefaultView

            objConn.Close()
        Finally


        End Try


    End If
End Sub
```

And this code imports/shows all the data in datagridview. I already search everywhere but nothing seems to fit. Thanks anyways..

This was the sample file:

```
CLIENT-RD/OT HC 8   7   8   10  11  12  10
C-RD/OT 6:00    0   0   0   0   0   0   0
C-RD/OT 7:30    0   0   0   0   0   0   0
C-RD/OT 8:00    0   0   0   0   0   0   0
C-RD/OT 9:00    8   7   8   10  11  12  10
C-RD/OT 10:00   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
C-RD/OT 12:00   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
C-RD/OT 1:30    0   0   0   0   0   0   0

ML      0   0   0   0   0   0   0
VL/SIL  2   4   1   1   1   2   2
SL         1    0   1   1   1   0   0

START                   20-Jan  21-Jan  22-Jan  23-Jan  24-Jan  25-Jan  26-Jan
CEBU                     MON    TUE      WED    THU       FRI       SAT   SUN
Team Edna - Esca                            
Adarayan, Dianne          RD    RD  6:00 AM 6:00 AM 6:00 AM 6:00 AM 1:30 PM
Bacalla, Catherine        VL    VL  RD/OT 7:30  7:30 AM 7:30 AM 7:30 AM RD
Dela Cruz, Mary Ann       6:00 AM   7:30 AM RD  RD  7:30 AM 7:30 AM 6:00 AM
Dumana, John Carlos       1:30 PM   1:30 PM 1:30 PM RD  RD  1:30 PM 1:30 PM
Macabodbod, Evelyn        9:00 AM   9:00 AM 9:00 AM 9:00 AM RD  RD/OT 9:00  9:00 AM
Mariano, Kristine         1:30 PM   RD/OT 1:30  1:30 PM 1:30 PM 1:30 PM RD  7:30 AM
Santiago, Gretchen        RD/OT 7:30    6:00 AM 7:30 AM 7:30 AM 1:30 PM 1:30 PM RD
END
```

Comment: first, dont do `SELECT *` specify the columns you want, namely those that relate to Columns B thru column I. that takes care of the column filtering.  For the rows, you might have to preprocess the CSV to move the lines between START and END to a new temp file that is loaded.  Does START AND END represent something else like a data range?  Edit your Post to add a LITTLE of the CSV as it is near to impossible to do data analysis with no data.

Comment: How to select specific colums in excel sir @Plutonix

Comment: if this is coming from Excel, why not extract and export the exact `range` you need rather than doing it in code?  Also, that does not look like a CSV - there are no Cs.  You might have to open it as text and extract the rows you want to a temp file.

Comment: The schedules are in .xls type file and the data i showed above is just a piece of all the data's in that file. My boss don't want to extract the data or columns/ rows anymore, rather she just wanted to upload the .xls file and let the system do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Dim objCmdSelect As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$B14:I24]", objConn)
```

lets assume **B14** is your `starting ROW` and **I24** is your last column/row record.

**UPDATED:**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv"

    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog(Me) = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

        Try
            Dim fi As New FileInfo(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
            Dim sConnectionStringz As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties=Text;Data Source=" & fi.DirectoryName & ";" & "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1"""
            Dim objConn As New OleDbConnection(sConnectionStringz)
            objConn.Open()

            Dim objAdapter1 As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$B14:I24]", objConn)

            Dim objDataset1 As New DataSet
            objAdapter1.Fill(objDataset1)

            DataGridView1.DataSource = objDataset1.Tables(0).DefaultView

            objConn.Close()
        Finally


        End Try


    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry but i got this error: "The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$B14_I24.txt'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly." The csv file is coming from the openDialogbox.

Comment: will you please use this... 
**Dim objAdapter1 As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$B14:I24]", objConn)**

skip **OledbCommand** instead directly use **OledbDataAdapter** just a try..

Comment: @Aljie Please see my updated post.. i add some properties in your connection string.

Comment: Thank you for your effort sir, i use your code and got this error message: "The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file 'C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop'.  It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data."

Comment: open task manager>services then end process all 'EXCEL' then run your app.

Comment: HI SIR, still getting the same error, but i'll start my pc right now and run the app again. Thanks again so muchh.

Comment: Hi Sir, still getting the same error even i ended all the 'EXCEL' process in the task manager.

Comment: Does the version of excel also affects the code ? Because im using ms excel 2003 right now.

Comment: yes it affects.. did yo use dll ? like interop?? or whatever?

Comment: I didn't sir. I just added the ms excel object in the referrence.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45867/discussion-between-aljie-and-unknownymous)